# HTTPS и Ajax не работают вместе

Tags: php, ajax, http, https

Перешел с http на https , все ajax запросы отправляются, кроме тех, что происходят таким образом:

```
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
             alert( "Страница готова!" );
         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Проблема была в том, что протокол у меня https, а в хедере я подключал jquery через http.